# How to set .indexOn in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my json structure

```
{
      "books" : {
        "sample" : {
          "eight" : {
            "author" : "eighta",
            "name" : "eight",
            "sub" : {
              "subauthor" : "eightauthor",
              "subname" : "general"
            }
          },
          "eleven" : {
            "author" : "twelvea",
            "name" : "twelve",
            "sub" : {
              "subauthor" : "elevenauthor",
              "subname" : "general"
            }
          },
          "five" : {
            "author" : "fivea",
            "name" : "five",
            "sub" : {
              "subauthor" : "fiveauthor",
              "subname" : "fivesub"
            }
          },
          "four" : {
            "author" : "foura",
            "name" : "four",
            "sub" : {
              "subauthor" : "fourauthor",
              "subname" : "general"
            }
          },
          "nine" : {
            "author" : "ninea",
            "name" : "nine",
            "sub" : {
              "subauthor" : "nineauthor",
              "subname" : "ninesub"
            }
          },
          "one" : {
            "author" : "onea",
            "name" : "one",
            "sub" : {
              "subauthor" : "oneauthor",
              "subname" : "onesub"
            }
          },
          "seven" : {
            "author" : "seven",
            "name" : "seven"
          },
          "six" : {
            "author" : "sixa",
            "name" : "six"
          },
          "ten" : {
            "author" : "tena",
            "name" : "ten"
          },
          "three" : {
            "author" : "threea",
            "name" : "three"
          },
          "two" : {
            "author" : "twoa",
            "name" : "two"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to fetch data which are having subname equal to general

My index rules

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "books": {
        "$user_id": {
          ".indexOn": ["subname", "subauthor"]
        }
        }
      }
  }
}

https://myprojectpath/books/sample/eight.json?orderBy="subname"&equalTo="general"&print=pretty
```

Above rule is working fine. But I need to pass generic api to fetch the data where subname should be general. I cannot pass eight.json, nine.json, ten.json each time when I call. I should call only one api where it should provide the data where subname should be general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to use a single query to search across all authors for their `sub/subname` property.

In that case you can define an index on `books/sample` for the `sub/subname` property of each child node:

```
"books": {
    "sample": {
        ".indexOn": ["sub/subname", "sub/subauthor"]
    }
}
```

The `sample` could be a `$` variable here (such a `$user_id`), but the paths in `.indexOn` have to be known.

This creates an index under `sample` with the value of `sub/subname` for each child node, which you can then query with:

```
https://myprojectpath/books/sample.json?orderBy="sub/subname"&equalTo="general"&print=pretty
```